# How do I fix the expected statement error on this code?

Tags: vbscript

To start.. I have no idea what I'm doing so go easy on me. I'm in this 'beginners' scripting languages class and I'm drowning. This weeks assignment is using VBScript to retrieve files from a folder and get each files name, size, and date created. I'm getting an expected statement error for the End. What do I do?? The teacher wants us to be 'defense' hence the If Else, but I don't even know if that's right. Here's the mess of a script I've put together:

```
Option Explicit

If obj.GetFolder = 0 Then
WScript.Echo "no folder to show"
Else

Dim fso, f, fc

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.GetFolder(folderspec)
Set fc = f.Files
For Each f1 In fc
    s = s & f1.Name
    s = s & f1.Size
    s = s & f1.DateCreated
Exit For
End
```

Comment: First, go away and read how the [`If` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/5h27x7e9(v=vs.84)) in VBScript is structured. There is no better resource than the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/t0aew7h6(v=vs.84)). The main issue here is the lack of `End If` instead of `End` and the missing `Next` to complete the `For` loop hence the "unexpected statement" errors.

Answer (score -1):

### List File Properties

**Simple With the Files Collection**

```
Option Explicit

Const fPath = "C:\Test"
Dim cSep: cSep = vbTab
Dim rSep: rSep = vbLf

Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FolderExists(fPath) Then
    Dim fsoFolder: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(fPath)
    Dim fsoFiles: Set fsoFiles = fsoFolder.Files
    If fsoFiles.Count > 0 Then
        Dim fsoFile
        Dim Result
        For Each fsoFile In fsoFiles
            Result = Result & fsoFile.Name & cSep
            Result = Result & fsoFile.Size & cSep
            Result = Result & fsoFile.DateCreated & rSep
        Next
        Result = Left(Result, Len(Result) - Len(rSep))
        WScript.Echo Result
    Else
        WScript.Echo "No files in folder '" & fPath & "'."
    End If
Else
    WScript.Echo "The folder '" & fPath & "' does not exist."
End If
```

**Simple Without the Files Collection**

```
Option Explicit

Const fPath = "C:\Test"
Dim cSep: cSep = vbTab
Dim rSep: rSep = vbLf

Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If fso.FolderExists(fPath) Then
    Dim fsoFolder: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(fPath)
    If fsoFolder.Files.Count > 0 Then
        Dim fsoFile
        Dim Result
        For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
            Result = Result & fsoFile.Name & cSep
            Result = Result & fsoFile.Size & cSep
            Result = Result & fsoFile.DateCreated & rSep
        Next
        Result = Left(Result, Len(Result) - Len(rSep))
        WScript.Echo Result
    Else
        WScript.Echo "No files in folder '" & fPath & "'."
    End If
Else
    WScript.Echo "The folder '" & fPath & "' does not exist."
End If
```

**Function With the Files Collection**

```
Option Explicit

Const fPath = "C:\Test"
Dim cSep: cSep = vbTab
Dim rSep: rsep = vbLf

Dim Result: Result = GetString(fPath, cSep, rSep)
If Len(Result) > 0 then
    WScript.Echo Result
End If 

Function GetString(fPath, cSep, rSep)

    ' File System Object

    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Folder Object   

    If Not fso.FolderExists(fPath) Then
        WScript.Echo "The folder '" & fPath & "' does not exist."
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim fsoFolder: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(fPath)

    ' Files Collection

    Dim fsoFiles: Set fsoFiles = fsoFolder.Files 
    If fsoFiles.Count = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "No files in folder '" & fPath & "'."
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' File Object

    Dim fsoFile
    Dim Result
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFiles
        Result = Result & fsoFile.Name & cSep
        Result = Result & fsoFile.Size & cSep
        Result = Result & fsoFile.DateCreated & rSep
    Next

    ' Result

    GetString = Left(Result, Len(Result) - Len(rSep))

End Function
```

**Function without the Files Collection**

```
Option Explicit

Const fPath = "C:\Test"
Dim cSep: cSep = vbTab
Dim rSep: rsep = vbLf

Dim Result: Result = GetString(fPath, cSep, rSep)
If Len(Result) > 0 then
    WScript.Echo Result
End If 

Function GetString(fPath, cSep, rSep)

    ' File System Object

    Dim fso: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' Folder Object   

    If Not fso.FolderExists(fPath) Then
        WScript.Echo "The folder '" & fPath & "' does not exist."
        Exit Function
    End If
    Dim fsoFolder: Set fsoFolder = fso.GetFolder(fPath)

    ' File Object        

    If fsoFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "No files in folder '" & fPath & "'."
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim fsoFile
    Dim Result
    For Each fsoFile In fsoFolder.Files
        Result = Result & fsoFile.Name & cSep
        Result = Result & fsoFile.Size & cSep
        Result = Result & fsoFile.DateCreated & rSep
    Next

    ' Result

    GetString = Left(Result, Len(Result) - Len(rSep))

End Function
```